# Is it possible to combine obfuscated files into one file using Pyarmor?

Tags: python, pyarmor

If I obfuscate test.py with Pyarmor, I would run a command like this:

```
pyarmor obfuscate test.py
```

However, using this code will generate multiple files.

As shown in the image below, in addition to the file test.py, a folder called pytransform is created.

[image]

When I distribute the obfuscated code to users, I must include this subfolder in the distribution. But I don't find this comfortable. I want to distribute the code to users in one file.

If it is a file binarized using PyInstaller, you can also distribute it as one file using innosetup etc. But for non-binary Script, I couldn't find a way to make it a single file.

Is there such a way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `pytransform` folder is generated the exact same every time. It never changes. As a result, if the recipient has a copy of the folder on their system (which they can easily generate using `pyarmor`), you don't need to send it to them, leaving you with only the one obfuscated file to send to them.